# Check and highlight the current day in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This function creates table with next 7 days, what I would like to achieve is to always highlight the current day in week. Any ideas how could I check the table content an apply a css..? Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xzgr9hf3/1/

This week should be represented through the whole week, Mon to Sun, so for example tomorrow I would like **only** **Tuesday** to be yellow

Like this:
(but with some sort of check)
    $( "td:contains('Mon Oct 23')" ).css( "background-color", "yellow" );

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var dat = new Date(this.valueOf())
  dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
  return dat;
}

function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
  var dateArray = new Array();
  var currentDate = startDate;
  while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
    dateArray.push(currentDate)
    currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
  }
  return dateArray;
}

var dateArray = getDates(new Date(), (new Date()).addDays(6));

var row = document.createElement("tr");
dateArray.forEach(function(item) {
  var cell = document.createElement("td");
  cell.textContent = item;
  row.appendChild(cell);
});

$('#table').append(row);

var todaysDate = new Date();

<div id="table"></div>
```

Comment: Your code will put current date as first date and so always the first date will be selected. Is that what you want? Or you want one whole week to display and then select current date?

Comment: Exactly, I want the whole week to be displayed and then select current date. I guess the current day should have some unique property through Date object..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop inside your table compare your date with today's date  and add class or style.

```
var todaysDate = new Date();
 $('#table tr td').each(function(index, element) {
   if ($(this).text() === todaysDate.toString()) {
     $(this).css("background-color", 'red');;
   }

 });
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzgr9hf3/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you always print the next 7 days, current day will always be the first element so you just need this instruction:

```
$("td").first().css("background", "yellow");
```

Here we go:

```js
 Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
        var dat = new Date(this.valueOf())
        dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
        return dat;

    }

    function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
        var dateArray = new Array();
        var currentDate = startDate;
        while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
            dateArray.push(currentDate)
            currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
        }
        return dateArray;
    }

    var dateArray = getDates(new Date(), (new Date()).addDays(6));

    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    dateArray.forEach(function(item) {
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        cell.textContent = item;
        row.appendChild(cell);
    });
    $('table').append(row);

    var todaysDate = new Date();
    
    $("td").first().css("background", "yellow");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```

Comment: Thanks this will also be useful, however maybe I wasn't clear enough: This week should be represented through the whole week, Mon to Sun, so for example tomorrow I would like only Tuesday to be yellow

Comment: Huh..wrapping my head around this one :D So for example on Friday I will be able to see Mon to Thu on the left/Sat-Sun on the right, and the Friday will be yellow?

Comment: As you programmed it, the first day shown will always be the current day

Comment: Yes I see now, that's quite fine, thanks... I am actually trying to display the whole week, and then select the current date - so on Wedneday for example I am able to see Mon and Tue unselected, but existing. Sort of a calendar, idea is to be able to navigate to next week with arrows

Answer (score 0):

Since your first element is alway the current date, you can:

```
dateArray.forEach(function(item, index) {
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    if (index === 0) {
        cell.style = "font-weight: bold;"
    }
    cell.textContent = item;
    row.appendChild(cell);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the current date and compare it with your range,in case your range wont start with current day.

```
 Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
        var dat = new Date(this.valueOf())
        dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
        return dat;

    }

    function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
        var dateArray = new Array();
        var currentDate = startDate;
        while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
            dateArray.push(currentDate)
            currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
        }
        return dateArray;
    }

    var dateArray = getDates(new Date(), (new Date()).addDays(6));

    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    dateArray.forEach(function(item) {
        var cell = document.createElement("td");

        cell.textContent = item;

        row.appendChild(cell);

        var curdate = new Date().getFullYear() + "-" + new Date().getMonth() + 1 + "-" + new Date().getDate();
        curitem = item.getFullYear() + "-" + item.getMonth() + 1 + "-" + item.getDate();
          console.log(curitem);
        if(curitem == curdate ){

        $( cell ).css( "background-color", "yellow" );

        }
    });
    $('#table').append(row);

    var todaysDate = new Date();
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzgr9hf3/6/)

Answer (score 0):

because actual date is the first element, you can select the first child of #table

After your append, you change the color of the td, but only first element, like this :

```
$('#table').append(row);
$('#table td:first-child').css({'color': 'red'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
new Date().getDay(); // week day index => cell
```

WITHOUT JQUERY :

```js
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var dat = new Date(this.valueOf())
  dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
  return dat;
}

function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
   var dateArray = new Array();
   var currentDate = startDate;
   while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
       dateArray.push(currentDate)
       currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
   }
   return dateArray;
}
   
 let table = document.getElementById('week')
   , dateArray = getDates(new Date(), (new Date()).addDays(6))
   , row = document.createElement("tr");
   
 dateArray.forEach(function(item) {
     var cell = document.createElement("td");
     cell.textContent = item;
     row.appendChild(cell);
 });
 table.appendChild(row);

 var todaysDate = new Date();

 // ------- HERE IS THE TRICK ---------       

 var curWeekDay = todaysDate.getDay();
 document
  .querySelectorAll('table#week td')[curWeekDay - 1]
  .style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
```

```html
<table id="week"></table>
```

WITH JQUERY:

```js
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var dat = new Date(this.valueOf())
  dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
  return dat;
}

   function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
       var dateArray = new Array();
       var currentDate = startDate;
       while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
           dateArray.push(currentDate)
           currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
       }
       return dateArray;
   }

   var dateArray = getDates(new Date(), (new Date()).addDays(6));

   var row = document.createElement("tr");
   dateArray.forEach(function(item) {
       var cell = document.createElement("td");
       cell.textContent = item;
       row.appendChild(cell);
   });
   $('table').append(row);


   var todaysDate = new Date();
   $("td:nth-child("+(todaysDate.getDay())+")").css("background", "yellow");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```